# Google pie chart shows opposite colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I have a pie chart that looks like this in the javascript:

```
function drawCurrentPieChart(title,days) {
    var name = document.getElementById("dropdownSubCategories").value;
    $
    .ajax({
        url : "piechartlist/",
        type : "GET",
        aync : true,
        dataType : "json",
        data : {days:days,
            categoryName : name + ""},
        error : function(e) {
            alert(e.message + "ERROR ");
        },
        success : function(response) {
            var jsonData = response;
            if (response == "") {
                alert("Error: Threshold is not valid or there is no status in the database within 24 hours.");
            } else {

                var data = [["Count","Color"]], colors = [];
                for(var c in jsonData){
                    data[data.length] = [jsonData[c]["color"],jsonData[c]["count"]];
                    colors[colors.length] = jsonData[c]["color"];
                }               

                data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

                var options = {
                        title: title,
                        'chartArea': {'width': '100%', 'height': '80%'},
                           'legend': {'position': 'bottom'},
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        colors : colors 
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'+days));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        }
    });
```

When it draws the chart, it shows the opposite colors that it recieves from the database (green is red, red is green etc.) What can be the problem?

Comment: It is connected to JAVA controllers, since its a spring object. You can see that it calls those functions in the url in ajax, sorry for no java code, I can include those if needed

Comment: It might be a java problem, thats why I also posted it here

Comment: What does your JSON response look like? Please add sample to your question

Comment: your example will work if to replace your `jsonData` by sample values: `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["Count", "Color"], ["red", 25], ["green", 20], ["blue", 30]]);          var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];`. So search issues in your java code.

Comment: I have checked the java code and replaced with case sensitive colors (if the server was unix instead of windows, which I've heard can be a problem) but that didn't solve the problem. What java code do you think can be the source of the problem?

Comment: If you post an example of `jsonData` returned by your server, we can identify if the problem is on your server or not.